# How To Use Static Reflection To Get The Name Of A Resx Resource Class Property?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, reflection, resx

I have numerous resx files in my project for localization for various languages.

I need to use static reflection to be able to get the property name of the resx class when using dot notation. For example:

MyStrings.This_is_a_test_string

I read several posts on static reflection and found the GetProperty method example which I converted from C# to VB using an online converter.

I attempted to use the following code:

```
Dim strPropertyName As PropertyInfo = GetProperty(DevStrings.This_is_a_test_string)

Public Function GetProperty(Of TEntity)(ByVal expression As Expression(Of Func(Of TEntity, Object))) As PropertyInfo

    Dim memberExpression As MemberExpression = TryCast(expression.Body, MemberExpression)

    If memberExpression Is Nothing Then Throw New InvalidOperationException("Not a member access.")

    Return TryCast(memberExpression.Member, PropertyInfo)

End Function
```

However, it results in this error:

BC36645: Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) in method 'Public Function GetProperty(Of TEntity)(ByVal expression As Expression(Of Func(Of TEntity, Object))) As PropertyInfo' cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.

I don't know anything about the reflection classes so I need very specific, step-by-step help.

Can anyone provide me with a working example in VB where I can get the name of the property reflected back to me a string?

In other words when I pass the parameter MyStrings.This_is_a_test to the reflection function I get back the string "This is a test"?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: ` Func(Of TEntity, Object)` So if the member is not `object`, then `expression.Body` will contain an implicit box or cast expression that you will need to ignore.

Comment: Second `GetProperty(DevStrings.This_is_a_test_string)` that is a property (ie a string), not a lambda `Function(x) DevStrings.This_is_a_test_string`

Comment: I already commented on the original question; in all of my uses, I don't infer the containing type for the property, so I'm not sure that can be inferred.  I think the property type could be inferred (as long as it's not in the context of a type argument list along with the containing type, as .NET doesn't support partial inference to my knowledge).

Comment: See my original comment for how you deal with the issue that Jeremy notes in his first comment.

Comment: Hi guys. Thank you for your replies. The code I listed is a sample I found on the Internet but is over my head. Can you provide sample VB code that may get the above scenario working? Thanks again for the help.